# type parameter in the response json: REST

Tags: json, rest, response, superclass

I sent a request JSON through Postmaster and got a response in which includes 
a field "type": "subPOJO", which isn't part of either my sub class or super class. How is it been placed in the response, if it is implicitly done then how to exclude it in the response. Thank you!

**Response JSON:**

```
{
  "type": "subPOJO",
  "superid": "XYZ",
  "name": "Rest Response",
  "number": 1212
}
```

**The Response POJOs:**

**Super class:**

```
package org.javaprojects.webapp.services;

public class SuperPOJO {
private String superid;

public String getSuperid() {
    return superid;
}

public void setSuperid(String superid) {
    this.superid = superid;
}
}
```

**Sub Class:**

```
package org.javaprojects.webapp.services;

public class SubPOJO extends SuperPOJO {

    private String name;
    private int number;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check this out](http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/05/jackson-json-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-of-subclasses-of-an-abstract-class/) This may Help you